# Is there any way to develop a report using apex class or visualforcepage?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have created reports from salesforce using reports and dashboard tab. I want to create a report using visual force page so that I can join more than 5 reports.
Is there any way to do this.

Comment: A Dashboard can get a visualforce page as one of its components, so you can develop something to include in a regular Dashboard, or you could develop a full Visualforce Page solution presenting data the way you want and have a link to the page itself instead of attaching to a Dashboard.

Comment: I did that. Its in dashboard. How can I do it in reports.